# Spring Security, Permission Evaluator with intercept-url

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing for myself small web application in which I'd like to have user with some permission to some actions. My database schema looks like following:
2 tables:

```
user (id, username, password, etc...)
user_permission (id, user_id, permission (as string) )
```

All told, each permission enables managing some data (add new employees, add new products etc.)

I have `CustomPermissionEvaluator` class(implementing `PermissionEvaluator`). It's corresponding bean is defined in another .xml file related to servlet.
Here's my code for security part of application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasPermission(#user,'ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/list"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
<beans:bean id="customUserService" class="com.mateuszprzybyla.security.CustomUserService"></beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

The line I'm struggling with for last 2 hours is

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasPermission(#user,'ROLE_USER')" />
```

I need it so that for all users who are not signed up login page shows up.
In database for sample user I have entity with `ROLE_USER` permission in `user_permission` table. When I enter website without being signed up, login page shows, and it's OK. But if I enter correct credentials and pass authorization step, 403 error shows (access forbidden). Moreover, during debugging, no `hasPermission` method is being invoked and that's the problem I've been trying to solve. When I tried to use `hasPermission` for single part of view (e.g. one table) it works perfectly.

Does anyone have idea what can be wrong with my configuration and, above all, why `hasPermission` method is not invoked? Should you have any questions about other classes, just ask for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the example you've given, it sounds like you are making things more complex than they need to be. Why not just follow the standard pattern of loading the roles for the user (the list of authorities), and using

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

To use the `hasPermission` expression you need to override the inbuilt `SecurityExpressionHandler` using the [`expression-handler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-expression-handler) option.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator{

@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
        Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {

    String desiredRoleName = (String) targetDomainObject;

if(authentication.isAuthenticated()) { // You don't need this 'if' block, if you have defined an anonymous ROLE for non-logged-in users in your security configuration.

    // Checking to see if the user has the roleName passed.
    for(GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authentication.getAuthorities()) {

        if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(grantedAuthority.getAuthority(), desiredRoleName)) {

            return true;

        } 
}
return false;

}

@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
        Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Not Implementing this.");
}
}
```

I don't see your `CustomPermissionEvaluator` class, so it's hard to say what's going wrong in your case. Here's a sample `PermissionEvaluator` implementation.
Typically the `GrantedAuthority` object inside the `Authentication` object should have the ROLE info unless you use a custom Authentication Manager. You may debug and see the object structure, the Authentication object should have the ROLE info somewhere in it.

If you don't see the ROLE info, you may wanna query the `user_permission` table yourself in the above code using the 'username' in the `Authentication` object above and if you use Hibernate or any Spring's transactional database templates, those annotations will not be bound in the `PermissionEvaluator` class above. You may end up defining a JDBCTemplate in the xml config file and bind that in your class to query your `user_permission` table.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same scenario.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasPermission(#user,'ROLE_USER')" />
```

please follow [spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access-web-beans)

In my case,

```
<intercept-url access="@webSecurity.checkPermission('chkValue')" pattern="/request"/>
```

Java

```
public class WebSecurity {

    public boolean checkPermission(String permission) {

        boolean hasPermission = true;
        try {
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                    .getRequest();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<String> functionList = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("FUNCTIONS");

            if (!functionList.contains(permission.toString())) {
                hasPermission = false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("WebSecurity URL Permission " + permission + "hasPermission :"+hasPermission);
        return hasPermission;
    }
}
```

Note: isAuthenticate() will authenticate all the URLs if the user is logged in. So please use *access="@webSecurity.checkPermission('chkValue')"* before that.

```
<intercept-url access="isAnonymous()" pattern="/login"/>            
<intercept-url access="@webSecurity.checkPermission('S000017')" pattern="/addRequest"/>
<intercept-url access="isAuthenticated()" pattern="/**"/>
```